# sudo raspi-config not working: boot partition not mounted

Tags: raspi-config, root

Just today I installed a version of Raspbian Jessie on my Raspberry Pi 2 model B. So, I wanted to disable the function that automatically sends the user to the GUI. But, when I typed in `sudo raspi-config`, it said:
`The boot partition is not mounted - cannot configure.` can anyone help me with this?

-CTECH 9

[The problem was solved long ago, so I'm closing the discussion. Thanks!]

Comment: Please make an answer an accept it after two days. Or accept one of the answers with a click on the tick on its left side. Only accepting an answer will finish your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mount of the boot partition is commented out by default in the `/etc/fstab` file.

Just remove the `#` sign from the line:

```
# /dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot     vfat  defaults     0   2
```

and after reboot the raspi-config is working again.

Comment: Maybe not such a good idea to comment out the mounting of /boot.

Comment: Thanks! The edit worked! Might make a vid on my youtube... Dunno why they'd have that commented off. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 8):

Check if your boot folder is empty using `cd /boot/` in a terminal session.  If so, you should be able to mount it to the SD card using a simple command.

`sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot`

All this command does is mount the boot partition on your SD card.  Which explains the `The boot partition is not mounted - cannot configure.` error.  `sudo raspi-config` looks for the `config.txt` which is located on the boot partition.  If the boot partition isn't mounted, `raspi-config` will not be able to find your `config.txt` file.  Thus, no configurations can be made.

That should do the trick.  However, if that doesn't work then there's another problem.  Good luck, tell me any other information about this problem if it comes up.

Comment: There is an error that says `mount: special device /dev/mmcblkop1 does not exist`. But, I'm using berryboot. Does that prevent the solution from working? (Also, is the  Pi3 update for Berryboot compatible with the Pi 2?)

Comment: @CTECH9 Can you go into your `/dev/` directory and list every file on there.  Send the info to me.

Comment: @CTECH9 It may not be that device.  For me, my boot partition was on the mmcblk0p5.  Also, you did say device mmcblk**o**p1.  That "o" should be a "0" (zero).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I was using Etcher with the `*.img` file I had extracted from the `*.zip` file. I flashed another time the card using the `*.zip` source file and it suddenly worked like a charm.